# solving power series expression?

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

Can anyone show how to simplify $$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^{n-1}}{(-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^n)^2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**small hint**

the derivative of $$\frac{1}{1-f}$$ is

$$\frac{f'}{(-1+f)^2}.$$

Comment: And starting from this (not so small) hint, a beautiful function appears. $+1$

Comment: whats the function

Answer (score 1):

> Hint: The *[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions)* admits the expansion
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!}=-W(-x)\qquad\qquad |x|<\frac{1}{e}
> \end{align*}